# How to share form input values with multiple cilents in realtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

For my graduation thesis I have to make a website for hardware repair company which will be used instead of information sheet to make it more comfortable. 
My question is, is there a way to show realtime form values (without submitting) to multiple clients at the same time?

Expected scenario would be following:

- Employee fills out company's information in their computer
- Client fills out theirs information and problem with their device from tablet

And they could both see what each-other type to the form.

I was looking towards socket.io because I know you can make realtime projects with it.

I would like to use Vuejs as front-end framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have already mentioned two potential technologies in your opening question. Indeed, Socket.io would allow you to open a network socket and up-date your UI in real-time. As for the framework you use to create the client is up to you, Vue, React or Angular, take your pick!

Comment: @philipjc I am pretty new to Socket.io, could you point out to some examples how come I could use socket.io to show something similar to  form's input data to multiple clients? I've looked into chat applications with socket.io, but in my opinion they are little different. Cheers.

Comment: I would create a quick app using the examples on Socket.io and log out the api data you are receiving. End of the day the DOM updates in real-time in a chat window, so all you are doing is replacing the chat window with form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following (very basic) example:

folders and files:

```
  server.js
  package.json
      -public
          index.html
          bix.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Bix</h1>
    <h3>
      first input: <input id='first' type='text' /><br><br>
      second input: <input id='second' type='text' /><br><br>
    </h3>     
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script src='bix.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http); 
const PORT = 5000;
app.use(express.static('public'));

http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('server listening on port ' + PORT);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('first', value => {
    io.emit('first', value);  
  });  
  socket.on('second', value => {
    io.emit('second', value);  
  });  
});
```

bix.js

```
const socket = io();
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

first.addEventListener('input', () => socket.emit('first', first.value));
second.addEventListener('input', () => socket.emit('second', second.value));

socket.on('first', value => { 
  first.value = value 
});

socket.on('second', value => {
  second.value = value;
});
```

Create the files, run `npm install`, run `node server`, open `http://localhost:5000` in two tabs and try it please.

It is only a hint, there's still a lot of work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO is a good option in my opinion. In fact a lot of nodejs folks prefer to use it. But, handling real-time data might be a bit painful for the first time. So, I would highly recommend [FeathersJS](https://feathersjs.com/). It has a powerful CLI to create CRUD operation in no time. Also, it allows both REST and Real-Time data transmission. It is based on ExpressJS.